# No Windows boot option after installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu

[image]

Here is the output of the `lsblk` command my issue was not able to resolve with the above command stated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) If you've tried everything there and it has not worked, then I recommend you **[edit]** this question will full details about exactly what you have tried and what happened (or why you were not able to attempt some things). If this is closed as a duplicate, you can still **[edit]** it and your edit will automatically get it reviewed for possible reopening.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt install os-prober
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
reboot
```

Edit your question with the output of

```
lsblk
```

if the above commands do not solve your issue.

Comment: the above command didnt solve my issue